# bootstrap card overlay wrap and truncate

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a web app and I am fighting with bootstrap cards. No matter what I do I can't get this to cooperate.

I have 5 cards in a row and I use the card overlay to add text to them. And I need the text to be multiline centered, wrap and if really long truncate. And all that responsive. Is it even possible?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/aaa/000.jpg&text=+">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <span class="hp-scene-text-center text-truncate">really long text that is so long that it doesnt fit in this cards overlay</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the `hp-scene-text-center` is

```
.hp-scene-text-center {
  font-size: larger;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: What's your definition of "really long"? You have a specific "height" of text you want to display before it truncates? Currently `text-truncate` only works for a single line.

Comment: Not really. Yeah, I am noticing this behavior. I don't have specific height as the card shrinks and extends based on the viewing device. Thinking about this more I am having second thoughts about this as it may turn out to be not really usable.